# How do I add a className to a React Component after scrolling using use-scroll-position?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to change the background color of a header (react component) from transparent to white when a user begins to scroll.

I'm using [this React Hook](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@n8tb1t/use-scroll-position) to get the window's current "y" position and am able to log that to confirm it's working. I am trying to learn both modern Javascript and React by building something and am hung up on this.

I'd like an event handler to see that I'm at a y-position greater than 0 and change that header className from the default state of transparent to "white" (or any className).

Here is where I am...I'm not sure where to go from here.

```
import React, { useState } from "react"
import { useScrollPosition } from "@n8tb1t/use-scroll-position"


const Header = () => {
  const [headerColor, setHeaderColor] = useState("transparent")
  useScrollPosition(
    ({ prevPos, currPos }) => {
      console.log(currPos.y)
    },
    [headerColor],
    false,
    false,
    300
  )

  return (
    (
      <header className={headerColor}>

        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <p>one</p>
            </li>
            <li>
              <p>two</p>
            </li>
            <li>
              <p>three</p>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </header>
    )
  )
}

export default Header
```

Comment: You're already there `if(curPos.y>0){setHeaderColor('white')}`

Comment: @HMR so this works, thanks. It's not in that code example, but I already have a few classNames assigned to header and simply want to add/remove a className on scroll (not wipe all existing classNames). any idea?

Comment: In your jsx you can do: `className={``one two three ${headerColor}``}` (replace `` with one tick since SO comments prevents me from putting correct code here)

Comment: @HMR thanks, I'm on the right track. For some reason the entire header is being replaced with the strings "white" and "transparent" (probably out of the scope of this question). But, I can see them swap in and out when scrolling.

Comment: figured it out. I had ```     </header>
    ),
    [headerColor]
  )
}``` which was causing the issue